# Change the Bootstrap using Bower of an MVC Core project with generated core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-code, bower

The author of [the ASP.NET Core MVC book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/148423149X) I am currently reading, presuming that the reader is using the Windows version of Visual Studio has described adding the Bootstrap package using Bower like this:
[image]
I am using VS Code and generated my entire MVC using the `dotnet` command. What I currently have in my project under `wwwroot` is a `lib/bootstrap` folder containing a `.bower.json` file (not `bower.json`) that contains a lot of settings.

[image]

I don't know where exactly should I place this new `bower.json` file and how to tell my project to use the new one instead.

I have also installed the Bower extension, but it asks one hundred questions and I am worried it would mess up my current structure.

Comment: Consider this as an information - Microsoft is dropping the support for Bower: https://wildermuth.com/2017/11/19/ASP-NET-Core-2-0-and-the-End-of-Bower; 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/07/05/workaround-for-bower-version-deprecation/

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your views so they will use bootstrap, most likely the View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml with something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/path/to/your/bootstrap.css" />
```

You don't have to do anything with your bower file, that's just a config file used by bower.
Btw, I suggest you using Visual Studio instead of VS Code for developing native .NET apps. There is a community edition for Windows and OSX as well.

Comment: Yes. But I like to learn how Bower works as well and not just point to the Bootstrap file and that was basically my question. Regarding Visual Studio, I installed the Community version for Mac until I realized plenty of features that I took for granted under Windows are missing. So, a Reddit user strongly recommended that I do not depend on it and described how he does his entire development with VS Code.

Comment: Bower is just a package manager, it just grabs packages and ensures it's consistency. In order to make a build pipeline for your front-end you may want to use Gulp/Grunt.